# Android device is not showing in PC

Tags: usb, drivers, android, kies

From yesterday onwards, my Samsung S4 is not showing anymore in my PC. Infact, all android devices are not showing.

Below is what I get when I connect my S4.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I installed Samsung drivers also from Samsung website but still its same.

Did anyone face such kind of issue?

***I have installed Kies too***

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you uninstall Kies?

Comment: @DavidPostill : still same... I think its virus issue.. even now PC is not working... :D :P

Comment: [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/q/100360)?